# WordPress: First Comment ID from current post

Tags: wordpress

Does someone know how to get the first comment ID from the current post?

I have already searched long for a good solution, but found nothing suitable.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_comments()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) returns an object. So you can just access the first one like any other object:

```
$comments = get_comments();
$first_comment_id = $comments[0]->comment_ID;
```

Comment: That wasn't me. Thank you for this answer. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following function to get comments of a post

```
<?php get_comments( $defaults ); ?>
```

It's default usage is as follows:

```
<?php 

$defaults = array(
'author_email' => '',
'author__in' => '',
'author__not_in' => '',
'include_unapproved' => '',
'fields' => '',
'ID' => '',
'comment__in' => '',
'comment__not_in' => '',
'karma' => '',
'number' => '',
'offset' => '',
'orderby' => '',
'order' => 'DESC',
'parent' => '',
'post_author__in' => '',
'post_author__not_in' => '',
'post_ID' => '', // ignored (use post_id instead)
'post_id' => 0,
'post__in' => '',
'post__not_in' => '',
'post_author' => '',
'post_name' => '',
'post_parent' => '',
'post_status' => '',
'post_type' => '',
'status' => 'all',
'type' => '',
    'type__in' => '',
    'type__not_in' => '',
'user_id' => '',
'search' => '',
'count' => false,
'meta_key' => '',
'meta_value' => '',
'meta_query' => '',
'date_query' => null, // See WP_Date_Query
);

?>
```

Make sure to edit the values as per your requirement. Using `get_comments()` you can get all comments and this way you can fetch first or any required comment id using loop.